# Unable to run ASP.NET Core migration in docker container

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, docker-compose

I have created Dockerfile for the backend api. I want to update my database before the application starts to run.

Below is the docker file

```
# Build Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /source
COPY ./orh-backend ./project
COPY ./function-script ./function-script
RUN dotnet restore "./project/md.api/md.api.csproj" --disable-parallel
RUN dotnet publish "./project/md.api/md.api.csproj" -c release -o /app --no-restore
WORKDIR /source/project/md.ef
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
RUN dotnet ef database update --context=TransactionDbContext

# Serve stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./

EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
# ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "orch.api.dll"]
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I run `docker compose build` below error comes
[image]

I was expecting tables to be created.

I have tried the below commands as well.

```
CMD ["dotnet", "ef", " database update  --context=TransactionDbContext" ]
```

```
ENV PATH $PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools
```

Comment: Comment out the last RUN in the build stage, then 'docker build' the build stage (with --t build). You should get a successful build. Then 'docker run --rm -it <the image tag or hash>' and you should arrive at a Bash prompt. From there you can explore the folder structure, test 'dotnet ef' interactively and try 'dotnet tool list --global' to see if what you expect to be installed is accurate.

Comment: The container will exit If I comment **Entrypoint**. FYI I am using `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: @ThomasF.Abraham I did and since the container(Serve stage) is using  `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal`  I can't run `dotnet tool/ef` commands because I need **.Net SDK**

Comment: You can test on a simple 2-line Dockerfile based on stripping down your first build stage into: <Dockerfile starts here>FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef<Dockerfile ends here> (Line breaks don't work in comments.) Build that Dockerfile with 'docker build' - not compose. Then use the 'docker run' command I mentioned to get to a Bash prompt in the container. You can interactively test as I mentioned above.

Comment: How did something so common and obvious got no solution?